# Cardinality of prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, cardinals, natural-numbers

I want to know the cardinality of the set of prime numbers. Is it aleph not? The cardinality of natural numbers and all countably infinite sets? But, how can we make a mapping of the set of prime numbers with the set of natural numbers? Is there such a mapping to impose the same cardinality on the set of primes as that of natural numbers?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107617/an-infinite-subset-of-a-countable-set-is-countable)

Comment: The mapping you're looking for is simply an enumeration of the prime numbers, for instance the one sending 1 to 2, 2 to 3, 3 to 5, and so on.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Did you mean aleph *naught*?

Comment: I will point out that the function described by BenSteffan certainly exists.  That it is *difficult to compute* is irrelevant.  It doesn't bother us that we have a difficult time saying within a short amount of time what the four-billionth prime number is.  It is obvious that there *is* a four-billionth prime number (*and indeed an $n$'th prime number for any finite $n$*) and that is all that we needed to convince ourselves of in regards to the validity of the existence of the described function.

Answer (score 1):

Any infinite subset $A$ of the natural numbers $\Bbb N$ must have cardinality $\aleph_0$: being infinite implies there is an injection $\Bbb N\to A$, and since $A$ is a subset of $\Bbb N$, the identity map forms an injection $A\to \Bbb N$.

By the [Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem) it follows that $|A|=|\Bbb N|=\aleph_0$.

---

In fact, you can make the above even stronger: any subset of the rational numbers, [algebraic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number) or even [computable numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number) is countable, since each of those sets is countable.